# How to stop html tags from auto closing in VBA?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Following the VBA documentation I have gone into the VBA settings and set the following:

```
{
  "html.autoClosingTags": false,
  "html.format.unformatted": ""
}
```

But the html tags still close. The problem I have is that in setting an EJS header view, I need to leave the `<html>` and `<body>` tags open (because they are closed in the footer, which is a separate file). But VBA forces my tags to close which breaks my formatting.

I have restarted and rebooted. Working on a linux/ubuntu OS.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I now realize this was a dumb question, and that it reflected my lack of understanding EJS, but I am leaving the question, commented as a reference. The problem of closing html tags breaking my styling was due to a poor implementation of EJS. For a very helpful and thorough explanation of EJS, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: Just for anyone who might come across this, I never did find a solution, BUT ... I do have a work around. Simply open the header and footer views in a different editor, that does not have this setting, and do your work in that editor.

This is probably better than turning off auto-closing html tags in VBA, because that is a useful property, and my case is an edge case.